tag getting cutoff in the UI
I was editing a question today and noticed that the ? link was being cut off in some tags, it seems to affect the ones with a long name. Looks like a bug in the website UI.


Might be better to post on meta.stackexchange as this is a general UI issue not specific to M&TV. Our moderators cannot change the UI.

That said I cannot reproduce in Chrome (latest version) and FF (Nightly)

They recently changed the font used in displaying tags across all of stack-exchange - this is probably fallout from that.

Can't seem to reproduce this in Firefox 126.0. What browser are you using?

@Paulie_D - Same. Seems like it's a user problem not a browser problem.

I'm on Chrome, macOS Sonoma 14. I'll try my luck on the main meta, thnks @Paulie_D
